# Adding sass to the project - installation not working - cb.apply is not a function

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, sass

I'm trying to use sass in my project, but installing sass isn't working in my windows 10 machine by using the command `npm i -g sass`. and I getting the following error in `npm-debug.log`

```
    0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Arun\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'i',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   'sass'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@3.10.10
3 info using node@v14.17.0
4 silly loadCurrentTree Starting
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData sass
8 silly fetchNamedPackageData sass
9 silly mapToRegistry name sass
10 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
11 silly mapToRegistry registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
12 silly mapToRegistry data Result {
12 silly mapToRegistry   raw: 'sass',
12 silly mapToRegistry   scope: null,
12 silly mapToRegistry   escapedName: 'sass',
12 silly mapToRegistry   name: 'sass',
12 silly mapToRegistry   rawSpec: '',
12 silly mapToRegistry   spec: 'latest',
12 silly mapToRegistry   type: 'tag'
12 silly mapToRegistry }
13 silly mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/sass
14 verbose request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/sass
15 verbose request no auth needed
16 info attempt registry request try #1 at 10:10:53 pm
17 verbose request id e008d98ed4542708
18 verbose etag W/"bf606690a2126312f5bf42d5684969d3"
19 verbose lastModified Sat, 22 May 2021 06:18:13 GMT
20 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sass
21 http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sass
22 verbose headers {
22 verbose headers   date: 'Sun, 23 May 2021 16:40:56 GMT',
22 verbose headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
22 verbose headers   'cf-ray': '653fba911aca31a6-BOM',
22 verbose headers   'cache-control': 'public, max-age=300',
22 verbose headers   etag: '"bf606690a2126312f5bf42d5684969d3"',
22 verbose headers   'last-modified': 'Sat, 22 May 2021 06:18:13 GMT',
22 verbose headers   vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
22 verbose headers   'cf-cache-status': 'REVALIDATED',
22 verbose headers   'cf-request-id': '0a3bb2eead000031a669266000000001',
22 verbose headers   'expect-ct': 'max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"',
22 verbose headers   server: 'cloudflare'
22 verbose headers }
23 silly get cb [
23 silly get   304,
23 silly get   {
23 silly get     date: 'Sun, 23 May 2021 16:40:56 GMT',
23 silly get     connection: 'keep-alive',
23 silly get     'cf-ray': '653fba911aca31a6-BOM',
23 silly get     'cache-control': 'public, max-age=300',
23 silly get     etag: '"bf606690a2126312f5bf42d5684969d3"',
23 silly get     'last-modified': 'Sat, 22 May 2021 06:18:13 GMT',
23 silly get     vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
23 silly get     'cf-cache-status': 'REVALIDATED',
23 silly get     'cf-request-id': '0a3bb2eead000031a669266000000001',
23 silly get     'expect-ct': 'max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"',
23 silly get     server: 'cloudflare'
23 silly get   }
23 silly get ]
24 verbose etag https://registry.npmjs.org/sass from cache
25 verbose get saving sass to C:\Users\Arun\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\registry.npmjs.org\sass\.cache.json
26 verbose correctMkdir C:\Users\Arun\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
27 verbose stack TypeError: cb.apply is not a function
27 verbose stack     at C:\Users\Arun\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:267:18
27 verbose stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:193:5)
28 verbose cwd C:\Users\Arun\Desktop\sass
29 error Windows_NT 10.0.19042
30 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Arun\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i" "-g" "sass"
31 error node v14.17.0
32 error npm  v3.10.10
33 error cb.apply is not a function
34 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
34 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
35 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

and in the console, I'm getting the following when installing sass

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.19042
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Arun\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i" "-g" "sass" 
npm ERR! node v14.17.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Arun\Desktop\sass\npm-debug.log
```

Any help really appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have oddly old npm version. You should update it running

```
npm i -g npm
```

Comment: That also results in the same error, is there any other way to get it done?

Answer (score 0):

This is for anyone who comes across the same issue.
I'm finally able to fix the problem.

Note: I'm using a windows machine

1. Go to C:\Users(your username)\AppData\Roaming
2. Delete `npm` and `npm_catche` folders
3. `npm cache verify` then
4. `npm cache clean --force`

its worked.